# I don't understand why this code seems to be buffering and I'm using unbuffered I / O

Tags: c, system-calls, glibc

In this simple code, I noticed that you are not reading stdin from the second read call, why is this happening? Since these functions are not buffered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(void) {
    char a, b;

    write(1, "first: ", 8); 
    read(0, &a, 1);
    write(1, "second: ", 10); 
    read(0, &b, 1);
    putchar(a);
    putchar(b);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Try typing `'x'`, backspace, `'y'`, enter.  What is `a`?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant, but anyway grateful for commenting

Comment: chux is demonstrating that the terminal has line editing capabilities (by showing you get neither the `x` nor the backspace from `read`), which means the terminal can't possibly provide data as it's typed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start your program and type (for example)

```
a [enter]
```

then two characters are pending on stdin: 'a' and '\n' (newline)

so the first call to `read()` blocks, waits for input and - after you enter the character - reads in the `a`.

The second call to `read()` does *not* block, but immediately reads the second pending character (the newline `\n`).

To fix this, you have to read in the newline into some dummy buffer, perhaps like this:

```
char a, b, dummy;

write(1, "first: ", 8); 
read(0, &a, 1);
read(0, &dummy, 1);
write(1, "second: ", 10); 
read(0, &b,  1);
read(0, &dummy, 1);
putchar(a);
putchar(b);
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: I noticed that the buffer is unloaded with the same newline character, just like functions that use stream, I thought that as the POSIX standard describes that the write and read syscalls do not use buffer, I thought I didn't have that, thanks for the answer, :)

Comment: Re "*the write and read syscalls do not use buffer*", They don't. But you do have to wait for the terminal to make data available, and it only does that on a newline. Same idea with a pipe or socket; you still need to wait for something to add data to the pipe or socket.

Comment: Wonderful, now I can understand well, why that happens.